# What should I do when R doesn't allocate vector of specific size?

Tags: r

I run a simple below command in R:

```
a <- merge(a,b,all.x=TRUE)
```

but suddenly this error comes and so I can't take the result of this command

```
cannot allocate vector of size 1.5 Gb
```

Do I need increase the memory? How should I do this?

Comment: operating system? R version?

Comment: remove unused objects with rm(), and then gc() to release memory

Comment: are you sure that `a` and `b` have some columns that match? You probably do not want to have all possible combinations of the two sets

Comment: they have not same rows i write a<- merge (a,b,by="ID",all.x=TRUE) in "a" one ID number have 3 or 4 reputation that was written in different rows.but in "b"  one ID number have exactly one reputation and I want to write each column of "b" for all row of "a" that have the same ID. is it correct?

Comment: I used gc() but it is not work in this situation